# Superfluid + Super conductivity in a bose condensate

Tags: superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

so my question is this

can we theoretically and empirically find a BOSE condensate, with SUPERFLUID properties but which is also

a SUPERCONDUCTING device ?

Answer (score 0):

A Bose-Einstein condenstate (BEC) is a purely non-interacting effect, and as such it is not technically a superfluid. However, since the superfluid critical velocity $v_c$ goes as the interaction strength $g$, a BEC, having $g = 0$, would have $v_c = 0$. So even if you *do* want to call it a superfluid, it's kind of a *boring* superfluid.

A superconductor is essentially the same as a superfluid but for a *charged* fluid, so that is composed of particles (elementary or not) that have an electrical charge.